# Wrong LaTeX output in arxiv

Tags: arxiv

In one of my arxiv articles, I am using listings environment combined with the tcolorbox package. Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[many,breakable,listings]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{nobeforeafter} 

\newtcblisting{mylistings}{%
    breakable,
    enhanced,
    size=fbox, 
    pad at break*=1mm,
    opacityfill=1,
    boxrule=1pt,
    before skip=\bigskipamount,
    after={\par\noindent},
    colback=lightgray,
    colframe=lightgray,
    attach title to upper,
    listing only,
    listing options={
        language=Python,
        upquote= true,
        tabsize=4,
        keywordstyle=\bfseries,
        basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
        basewidth=.5em,
        aboveskip=0pt,
        belowskip=-2pt,
        showstringspaces=false,
        breaklines=true,
        sensitive=true,
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{mylistings}
%display latex
\end{mylistings}
\end{document}
```

In arxiv, it appears to happen that the text after the % sign vanishes even though everything works fine on all of my machines.

---

**Edit 07/22/2020:**

The output in arxiv looks as follows:

[image]

Comment: Remember that arxiv is using a 4+ years old latex installation (probably texlive 2016). Tcolorbox have probably got some updates since then. Might not be a good idea to apply advanced packages for stuff that goes onto arxiv

Comment: Well, this article is my thesis, and at that time I wrote it, I had other things in mind. Probably, there are special commands to mimic the wanted behavior?

Comment: I think it is possible to only submit a pdf file on arxiv, file that was compiled on your personal computer.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not. arxiv recognizes LaTeX written code and requires to upload the source code. There are tricks possible, like including the pdf in another LaTeX document, yes. However, it would be nice when it can be worked out without any tricks.

Comment: What is the trick of including a pdf in another Latex document? Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your minimal working example appears to work just fine in arXiv, and compiles with identical output in texlive 2020. [image: minimal working example, compiled in arXiv]

I see that it's rotating due to the stamping operation, so if you want to disable that, you'll need to supply a `00README.XXX` plain text file with the appropriate [control value](https://arxiv.org/help/00README#nostamp). If you are having a specific issue, please contact [arXiv help](https://arxiv.org/help/contact) along with your `submit-id` for specific assistance relative to your source.

Comment: I checked again, and the text after the percent sign still vanishes in arxiv. I've added a screenshot in my original post. In case this might be important: I use arxiv-collector to upload the tex file.

Comment: It looks like the `arxiv-collector` package is stripping comments. I see in the submission uploaded to arXiv, that there's nothing after the %.

Comment: (as an arXiv admin, I can see these things when I have the submit-id, which was why I suggested pinging help earlier)

Comment: according to the project site for https://github.com/djsutherland/arxiv-collector it looks like the default behavior is to strip the comments. So what's being left behind is just the %, which explains the output of what you're seeing.

Comment: Okay, that's perfect. Then I know where the behavior comes from, and I can fix this. Thank you! :)